# How to setup GridDB on macOS

Tags: macos, griddb

As macOS is not listed as a server operating system supported by GridDB, what is the best way to setup GridDB in macOS for the Data Analysis purpose?

Comment: Have you tried installing it from source code?  As per https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/

Comment: Not Yet, I have tried installing it on CentOS image using Docker though. Stuck there too.  It says ==> chown: invalid user: 'gsadm:gridstore' . @AlekseyTsalolikhin

Comment: Sounds like the gsadm user doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best suited using docker: https://hub.docker.com/r/griddb/griddb

once it's set up, you can test with the clients as shown in the readme