# fallocate on MacOS for GridDB configure

Tags: macos, griddb, fallocate

I have been trying to install GridDB on MacOS to do some big data work, but hitting issues.

I have checked other questions on SO, and took the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417623/how-to-setup-griddb-on-macos) to try from [source code](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/#build-a-server-and-client-java).

The configure step fails with:

```
    checking whether FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE is declared... no
    configure: error: fallocate and FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE must be supported`
```

How can get fallocate on MacOS?

Comment: getting the same error here as well any solutions yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, Johhn.