# GridDB automake warnings on MacOS

Tags: macos, automake, griddb

I am trying to build GridDB from source code on MacOS as recommended [How to setup GridDB on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417623/how-to-setup-griddb-on-macos) with instructions https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-source-code/#build-a-server-and-client-java.

During the automake step, I get the following warning(s) for many source files:

```
    3rd_party/MessagePack/Makefile.am:8: warning: source file '$(srcdir)/src/objectc.c' is in a subdirectory,
    3rd_party/MessagePack/Makefile.am:8: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
```

Has anyone else had this? Any advice of how to make solve this warning? Is it critical in the make process?

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between a *warning* and an *error*.

Both indicate problems, but while an *error* indicates a **fatal** problem that requires a solution *right now*, a *warning* is just that: a hint that there's a **potential** problem.

So: there's no need to *solve* anything right now.

As a *user* (of GridDB), you (normally) can ignore any such warning.
However, the *maintainers* (of GridDB) should look into that, as the warning might turn into an error as the world outside evolves.

Having said that, afaict not using `subdir-objects` with sources in subdirectories is not a problem per se, and some might prefer it that way. `automake`  tries to push towards `subdir-objects`, as it fixes problems if you have multiple files with the same name in different directories. However, this (multiple same-named files in different directories) is not the case *here*.